# Implementing refresh token in Web API Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, webapi

I need to implement refresh token in my Web API. I found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/) article, so I need to elaborate further with implementation of refresh token. As well, I found some tutorials how to do it, but I do not have idea how to start in my use case. This is the action in my Auth controller responsible for login, and generating token:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            if (user != null &&
                await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password) &&
                await userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {
                var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                };

                foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                {
                    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                }

                var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"], // The first parameter is a simple string representing the name of the webserver that issues the token
                    audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"], // The second parameter is a string value representing valid recipients
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(15), // DateTime object that represents the date and time after which the token expires
                    claims: authClaims, // a list of user roles, for example, the user can be an admin, manager or author
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

**Any idea how and where to start?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using IdentityServer4. Everything you need for OAuth token authentication is already implemented there. You can enable refresh tokens with couple of simple configurations.

Here for more information:  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And more about the refresh tokens: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html

IdentityServer is part of the .NET Foundataion: https://dotnetfoundation.org/projects/identityserver

Answer (score 0):

You could create a refresh token entity or add a property in the Login model to store the refresh token, and set it's expired time. After getting the refresh token, you could store it in the cookie. Try to search "asp.net core JWT refresh token authentication" online, you will find lots of tutorials, such as:

[ASP.NET Core 3.1 API - JWT Authentication with Refresh Tokens](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/25/aspnet-core-3-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens)

[Implement JWT In .NET Core API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-jwt-in-net-core-api/)

[Using Refresh Tokens in ASP.NET Core Authentication](https://code-maze.com/using-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a try/catch on your method that calls the remote API, and as soon as it fails due to the expired token, you can initiate a renewal of the refresh token and try again.

Like this:

```
        public async Task<TResponse> ExecuteWithRetryAsync<TResponse>(Func<Task<TResponse>> webApiCallMethod)
        {
            var tryForceRefreshToken = false;
            var attemptsCounter = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (tryForceRefreshToken)
                {
                    var success = await TryAuthWithRefreshTokenAsync();
                }
                try
                {
                    attemptsCounter++;

                    var response = await webApiCallMethod.Invoke();
                    return response;
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException)
                {
                    if (attemptsCounter > 2)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    tryForceRefreshToken = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

And as soon as it fails you attempt to execute a TryAuthWithRefreshTokenAsync a method for attempting to refresh the token by using your expired bearer token, as this:

```
        private async Task<bool> TryAuthWithRefreshTokenAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                //Tenta executar o refreshtoken apenas da primeira thread que solicitou...
                //Para as demais threads, faz com que elas aguardem pela renovacao do token.
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _refreshTokenEntered, 1, 0) == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Refresh Token Renewing...");
                    //tenta renovar
                    var authResponse = await AuthWithRefreshTokenAsync();
                  
                    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _refreshTokenEntered, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Refresh Token Renewed");
                    return authResponse.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Refresh Token Renewal is Waiting...");

                    while (_refreshTokenEntered == 1)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                    }
                    //Faz as outras threads aguardarem até que o token seja renovado no bloco anterior
                    Console.WriteLine("Refresh Token Renewal done!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _refreshTokenEntered, 0);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

After a successfull bearer token renewal the method ExecuteWithRetryAsync can try again and call your remote web api.

For more please see [here](https://thenextloop.com/2020/09/21/a-better-approach-for-consuming-back-end-services-and/).